# Getting text from dynamic html

Tags: javascript

I would like to get messages/ text that are typed in the input box "chat-inputboxval" into c# when the user click the send button this is a Facebook style popup box. Each user will have there own chat box. (and the user name and ID)

c# script:

```
  function register_popup(id, name) {

        for (var iii = 0; iii < popups.length; iii++) {
            //already registered. Bring it to front.
            if (id == popups[iii]) {
                Array.remove(popups, iii);

                popups.unshift(id);

                calculate_popups();


                return;
            }
        }

        var element = '<div class="popup-box chat-popup" id="' + id + '">';
        element = element + '<div class="popup-head">';
        element = element + '<div class="popup-head-left">' + name + '</div>';
        element = element +
            '<div class="popup-head-right"><a href="javascript:close_popup(\'' +
            id +
            '\');">&#10005;</a></div>';
        element = element + '<div style="clear: both"></div></div><div class="popup-messages"></div>';
        element = element +
            '<div class="chat-inputbox" ><input type="text" class="chat-inputboxval"  /></div></div>';

        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
            .innerHTML = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML + element;

        popups.unshift(id);

        calculate_popups();
    }
```

Comment: This is javascript.

Comment: On a sidenote, you probably need to know [Multi-Line JavaScript Strings](https://davidwalsh.name/multiline-javascript-strings)